# TextView SetText Time

Tags: android, layout, textview

I wrote a simple android code that just set text to android textView like this:

```
String all = "";
String sample = "a sample text...";

long start = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) {
    all += sample;
    txtContent.setText(all);
}
long end = SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis();

Log.d("set text time", "time: " + (end - start));
```

txtContent is a TextView on my layout which is inside of a simple LinearLayout

I run this code in two circumstances:

txtContent `layout_width = "wrap_content"`

and `layout_width = "match_parent"` (or any const value)

Surprisingly when I set `layout_width = "wrap_content"` it takes much less time to complete for loop than set `layout_width = "match_parent"` or any const value.

Can somebody help me to find out why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

use a parent linearlayout

and put your textview in linearlayout

parent linearlayout should center inner textviews like that,

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">
```

Comment: Thanks; but it's not my answer. I wanna know if you can explain the measuring system which done to set text into textview

Comment: I can't understand it but do you want to update textview every second ?

Comment: Yes, I'm writing something like epub reader and I read one paragraph each time and I should read just enough text to be fit into textview. So I have to read one paragraph and set to textview and check whether It's full or not. So this is important to set the text efficiently into textview

Comment: What do you mean "I should read just enough text to be fit into textview"?? What kind of FIT are we talking about here??

Answer (score 0):

So.. you should do something like that,

```
int lastSeconds = 0;
Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                             lastSeconds+=1;
                             textView.setText(lastSeconds)
                        }
                    }, 1000);
```

or you can ,

```
textView.post(Runnable...)
```

Also , you should make "minute:second" like string format..

Another way is , you can use Chronometer

*If i understood your question...*